# MongoDB, find items matching the term "a" & $nin

Tags: php, mongodb

i'm trying, to figure out how can i make this query work in mongodb.

This is the query i'm trying to do ( "translated" to mysql )

`SELECT title FROM artists WHERE name LIKE "%a%" AND id NOT IN(1, 2)`

The try in mongoDB

`$term = new MongoRegex('/^a/i')l;`

`$not = array('$nin' => array('_id' => array('1', '2')));`

1. `$artists->find(array('name' => $term), $not);`
2. `$artists->find(array('name' => $term, $not))`;

how can i make this work as expected, right now it returns `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for mongodb

```
db.artists.find({
   "name" : /a/,
   "id" : {
        "$nin" : [1,2]
   }
})
```

just by writing each {} as an array, you will get the answer for php